# Validating Text boxes and drop down lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I am currently working on a visual studio asp.net website and have a web aspx page with textboxes drop down lists, and a submit button at the bottom of the page. I want the submit button to not function unless all the text boxes are filled and a selection from the drop down menu is made...how can i do this the easiest way possible? I have tried using required field validators and done research still cant seem to achieve this... any help would be great!

Comment: why your required field validators are not working? You need to post your code, explain in details to get help from others

Answer (score 0):

I would use for textbox validation Angular and JavaScript which you could integrate with your ASP.NET project. With angular you can use ng-disabled to disabled a button it's very easy.